# An old film where they idolize engineers

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's an old movie where they "idolize" engineers.

There is a scene where they are chased by a giant rat or shrew.

At the end one of the characters manages to escape from the city where they were locked up.

Comment: Hi, warm welcomes to the site! I've crudely translated your question, but I think you will need to add a lot more details with an [edit]. Please do so in English, and include things like the year your saw it and the language of the film.

Comment: Bien hecho @AncientSwordRage

Comment: The giant rat/shrew sounds sci-fi if nothing else.

Comment: This question makes me think of the City of Ember movie.

Comment: Me too @Dosco Jones! Giant mole wasn't it?

Comment: Yes, giant mole.

Comment: ¿El Jajas, conoces la pelicula "City of Ember"?